# Can a 3DS receive DS Download Play games from DS cartridges?

Tags: nintendo-ds, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Can the 3DS receive and play games from the regular DS (DS, DSi, DS Lite, DSi XL)?  For example, Tetris from Tetris DS or Mario vs Luigi from New Super Mario Bros.  Or will I lose the ability to play these games with my DS-friends once I upgrade to a 3DS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will still be able to use the Download Play on the 3DS - I've done it, and it works quite well. :)

Answer (score 5):

When you use "download play" on the 3ds, you need to choose if you'll be loading a 3ds or a ds game. Choose the latter, and the answer to your question is yes.